# Validation does not execute in service layer

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

hibernate-validator does not work in service layer on my spring boot project.

My domain model:

```java
@Data
public class IssueAttachmentDto extends AttachmentDto {

    @NotEmpty
    private String issueId;

}

@Data
public class AttachmentDto {

    /**
     * Only allow digit 1~5
     */
    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp = "\\b[1-5]\\b")
    private String attachmentType;

    @NotEmpty
    @Valid
    private FileDto fileDto;
}

@Data
public class FileDto extends BaseDto {

    @NotEmpty
    private String fileType;

    /**
     * Only allow positive integer
     */
    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$")
    private Long fileSize;

    @NotEmpty
    private String fileKey;

    @NotEmpty
    private String fileName;
}
```

My service class:

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
@Validated
public class AttachmentServiceImpl implements AttachmentService { 
  @Override
  public void uploadAttachment(IssueAttachmentDto issueAttachmentDto) {
    try {
      checkUploadAttachmentArgument(issueAttachmentDto);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw e;
    }
        // something else...
  }

  private void checkUploadAttachmentArgument(@Valid IssueAttachmentDto issueAttachmentDto) {
    // something else
  }
}
```

My config class:

```java
@Configuration
public class ConversionConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConversionService conversionService() {
        return new DefaultConversionService();
    }
}
```

The method `checkUploadAttachmentArgument(@Valid IssueAttachmentDto issueAttachmentDto)` never throws an exception whatever I pass. In my suppose, it will throws a ConstraintViolationException when I pass the illegal data. What's wrong with my code or my configuration, please help me.

Comment: first you can remove the `@Validated` annotation that serves no purpose its is used for validation groups. Do you even have Hibernate validator or any other validator on your classpath?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Yes, I am sure my validator is on my classpath. If not that so how can I compile above codes?

Comment: you can compile you code because you are using spring annotations and JSR-303 specific annotations. You can without any problem use these annotations without having any underlying validation implementation on your classpath, because these are only specification annotations. They are not the actual implementation. Since you have not posted your pom.xml i had to clear that up.

Comment: Thanks your rely. Finally I solved my problem by new a validator manually and used this validator to validate my bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring cannot proxy private methods - that is why you don't see any exception being thrown when invalid object is passed as an argument.

Simply move the `@Valid` annotation to `uploadAttachment` method argument and it should work as expected. It should look like this:

```
public void uploadAttachment(@Valid IssueAttachmentDto issueAttachmentDto) {
    // actual upload attachent logic
}
```

**Edit:**

Even if Spring could proxy private methods it would not validate annotated argument in your case as you actually call `checkUploadAttachmentArgument` on an instance of the original class and not a proxy that additionally perform validation.

Comment: Thanks your answer firstly. But I still can not catch any exception after I change the  `checkUploadAttachmentArgument(@Valid IssueAttachmentDto issueAttachmentDto)` as this: `public void checkUploadAttachmentArgument(@Valid IssueAttachmentDto issueAttachmentDto) {
}`

Comment: Yeah, you won't catch any exception - I've updated my answer with explanation why. You don't need `checkUploadAttachmentArgument` method at all, simply modify `uploadAttachment` method like in example above.

Comment: I still couldn't get any exception after I follow your example when I pass `attachmentType = 8`.

Comment: How do you test it?

Comment: `IssueAttachment foo = new IssueAttachmentDto(); foo.setAttachmentType("8"); attachentService.uploadAttachment(foo)`

Comment: Is `attachementService` a bean created by Spring or explicitly by you?

Comment: Yes, I get `attachementService` from Spring IoC.

Comment: Yeah, I thought you are right because the method with `@Valid` could not been invoked manually if I want use the function of `@Valid`. Therefore I set this question as solved.